# Pythonnet output with a C# method that accepts a reference to ListItem

Tags: list, listitem, python.net

I am working with a C# method that will get me a list of indices via the following syntax:

`Public Sub GetValues(ByRef Values() As ListItem)`

I was under the impression that because this is an out method, I should be able to pass a dummy value to this method in python and get the value out like the following:

`outputList = obj.getValues(dummyItem)`

It looks like System.Collections.Generic has List<> but does not have ListItem, meaning there is no value I can pass to the getValues method that will allow me to call it successfully. Is there a workaround here?